# Haproxy Nginx/Naxsi to Web servers not working

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, haproxy

I have a haproxy/nginx/naxsi setup for load balancing and security. Traffic is supposed to come into haproxy then to nginx/nasxi then finally to the web servers if they passed the WAF. We also have a differnet IP address in the front then we do in the back.

What the heck am I doing wrong where it won't flow through nginx? I only get 503 errors when going through nginx, if I bypass nginx/naxsi it works as intended.

Inet -> Haproxy .5.3:80 -> .5.3:81 Nginx/Naxsi .6.3:81 -> .6.x:80 Web Servers

```
frontend ft_waf
  bind 10.0.5.15:80 name http
  mode http
  log global
  option httplog
  timeout client 25s
  maxconn 10000

  # DDOS protection
  # Use General Purpose Couter (gpc) 0 in SC1 as a global abuse counter
  # Monitors the number of request sent by an IP over a period of 10 seconds
  stick-table type ip size 1m expire 1m store gpc0,http_req_rate(10s),http_err_rate(10s)
  tcp-request connection track-sc1 src
  tcp-request connection reject if { sc1_get_gpc0 gt 0 }
  # Abuser means more than 100reqs/10s
  acl abuse sc1_http_req_rate gt 100
  acl kill sc1_inc_gpc0 gt 10
  acl save sc1_clr_gpc0 ge 0
  tcp-request connection accept if !abuse save
  tcp-request connection reject if abuse kill
  acl no_waf nbsrv(bk_waf) eq 0
  acl waf_max_capacity queue(bk_waf) ge 1
  # bypass WAF farm if no WAF available
  use_backend bk_web if no_waf
  # bypass WAF farm if it reaches its capacity
  default_backend bk_waf

# WAF farm where users' traffic is routed first
backend bk_waf
  balance roundrobin
  mode http
  log global
  option httplog
  option forwardfor header X-Client-IP
  # If the source IP generated 10 or more http request over the defined period,
  # flag the IP as abuser on the frontend
  acl abuse sc1_http_err_rate gt 10
  acl kill sc1_inc_gpc0 gt 0
  tcp-request content reject if abuse kill
  # Specific WAF checking: a DENY means everything is OK
  timeout server 25s
  server waf1 10.0.5.3:81 maxconn 10000 check

# Traffic secured by the WAF arrives here
frontend ft_web
  bind 10.0.6.3:81 name http
  mode http
  log global
  option httplog
  # route commerical domains to com_web
  acl is_comm hdr(host) -i -f /etc/haproxy/commweb
  use_backend com_web if is_comm
  acl is_comwbm hdr(host) -i -f /etc/haproxy/webmailredirect
  redirect location http://newwebmail.example.net if is_comwbm
  timeout client 25s
  maxconn 1000
  default_backend bk_web

backend com_web
  balance roundrobin
  mode http
  log global
  option httplog
  option forwardfor
  cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
  default-server inter 30s rise 2 fall 3
  option httpchk HEAD /
  # get connected on the application server using the user ip
  # provided in the X-Client-IP header setup by ft_waf frontend
  source 0.0.0.0 usesrc hdr_ip(X-Client-IP)
  timeout server 25s
  server comserver01 10.0.6.22:80 maxconn 10000 weight 10 cookie server1 check

# application server farm
backend bk_web
  balance roundrobin
  mode http
  log global
  option httplog
  option forwardfor
  cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
  default-server inter 30s rise 2 fall 3
  option httpchk HEAD /
  # get connected on the application server using the user ip
  # provided in the X-Client-IP header setup by ft_waf frontend
  source 0.0.0.0 usesrc hdr_ip(X-Client-IP)
  timeout server 25s
  server webserver01 10.0.6.10:80 maxconn 10000 weight 10 cookie server1 check
  server webserver02 10.0.6.11:80 maxconn 10000 weight 10 cookie server2 check
  server webserver03 10.0.6.12:80 maxconn 10000 weight 10 cookie server2 check
  server webserver04 10.0.6.13:80 maxconn 10000 weight 10 cookie server2 check
```

```
http {
 include        /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;
 include        mime.types;
 server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

 sendfile        on;
 keepalive_timeout  65;
 tcp_nodelay        on;

 gzip  on;
 gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

server {
 proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "";
 listen       10.0.5.3:81;
 access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

 location / {
   include    /etc/nginx/test.rules;
   proxy_pass http://10.0.6.3:81/;
  }
```

Comment: What do your Nginx logs tell you? What about HAProxy? Have you tried sniffing traffic between HAProxy and Nginx to see what's going on? In short, what troubleshooting steps have you taken?

Comment: I've looked at both haproxy and nginx's logs. The haproxy logs show me that it's going in the right direction and sending along the right information. The nginx logs don't show any errors but in the access log show this

GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 118 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.71 Safari/537.36
 when attempting to go to one of our fqdn domain.

Comment: Try putting naxsi in Learning Mode and see what happens. My guess is that naxsi does actually reject your connection. Also, any reason why you are using a load balancer before a proxy/firewall? It would make way more sense to go the other way around. Or even remove haproxy altogether if it doesn't provide you much benefit.